# mathematica how to eliminate variable name after solving

Tags: variables, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to solve equations and output the derivations. I have no problem solving for the derivation but when I try to output the derivation it always comes with the variable name, examples:

```
{{w0fromxfun1[x] -> (8.46504 miu^(4/9) qi^(4/9) (-1. x + xf)^(4/9))/
   Ep^(4/9)}}
{{uave[x] -> (0.382926 Ep^(1/4) qi^(3/4))/(
   hf (miu (-1. x + xf))^(1/4))}}
```

[See this link for a better view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubEUA.png)

My code for solving the derivation is here:

```
equ5 = uave[x] == ((qi Ep^(1/3))/(
    3.59623 hf (hf miu (xf - x))^(1/3)))^(3/4);
diffequsol2 = PowerExpand[FullSimplify[DSolve[equ5, uave[x], x]]] // N;
waveofthemaxes = 
  FullSimplify[
   1/xf Integrate[w0fromxfun[x], {x, 0, xf}, Assumptions -> trivial]];
equ6 = w0fromxfun1[
    x] == ((4.5788*(hf miu qi/((\[Pi]/4)  hf ) (-x + xf))^(1/3))/Ep^(
     1/3))^(4/3);
diffequsol1 = 
 PowerExpand[FullSimplify[DSolve[equ6, w0fromxfun1[x], x]]] // N
```

[See here for a better view of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fasZf.png)

I don't want the variable names in front of the derivations, I tried `Fullsimplify` and `simplify` but don't work.

Comment: Mathematica returns "rules" in the form of name->value so you can use that value in different ways. If all you want are the values then use uave[x]/.diffequsol2[[1]] and w0fromxfun1[x]/.diffequsol1[[1]] to get those. Look up /. or ReplaceAll in the help system and see if you can understand how these work. You will find this used in many places in Mathematica. I also used [[1]] to get rid of { and } around your values. Look up [[ or Part in the help system to understand these.

Comment: note as of version 10, some functions such as `DSolve` have a sister function `DSolveValue` that do essentially the same thing but provide the result directly instead of in rule form.